# Why it's so difficult to find a simple value of variable in xcode?

Tags: xcode4.5

[image]

It's not available on the lower left screen thingy. If I do po self.delegate.tvDelegated it doesn't work either.

It's simple looking at some variable value. What's the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes is better to use the original method sending, instead of dot notation, even if in the latest version support mors dote, try to write

```
po [[self delegate] tvDelegated]
```

Comment: And htey haven't fix this up till now?

Comment: I thought dot notation works. Now it doesn't. The bracket notation works.